# Why does Perl's sprintf not round floating point numbers correctly?

Tags: perl, floating-point, printf

I was out looking for the rounding convention used by Perl's built-in function [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html).

I was thinking that it does a normal rounding (e.g. ROUND_HALF_UP as in [Java's rounding mode convention](http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html)), but digging further proved this to be wrong:

```
> /usr/local/bin/perl5.10.1 -e 'print(sprintf("%.2f", shift @ARGV)."\n");' 0.335
0.34
> /usr/local/bin/perl5.10.1 -e 'print(sprintf("%.2f", shift @ARGV)."\n");' 1.335
1.33
```

Comment: print(sprintf(...))?  I wonder if there is a "printf"...

Comment: Have a look at [Perl Cookbook recipe 2.2 - rounding floating-point numbers](http://books.google.com/books?id=hP4IRp8xwTkC&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=rounding+numbers+perl+cookbook&source=bl&ots=ti7Tyxr3s7&sig=gyWX-iySyiVZef0vB43ZuIaxkuw&hl=en&ei=RPzrStmzO4z0MarIvKkI&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CAwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=&f=false)
 for a more complete explanation

Answer (score 16):

You have been bitten by the fact that floating point numbers are not exact representations of decimal fractions.  Here's what I get:

```
  DB<1> $a=0.335

  DB<5> print sprintf("%.19f",$a)
0.3350000000000000200
  DB<7> $b=1.335

  DB<8> print sprintf("%.19f",$b)
1.3349999999999999645
  DB<9>
```

Since 0.335 is represented internally as slightly larger than 0.335 it rounds to .34, while 1.335 is slightly LESS than 1.335, so it rounds to 1.33.

Answer (score 6):

This is a function of IEEE floating point numbers.

For more information, in a Perl context, see [Perlfaq4 "Does Perl have a round() function"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#Does-Perl-have-a-round()-function%3f--What-about-ceil()-and-floor()%3f--Trig-functions%3f) and in particular what it says about  half-way-point alternation.