# Consistent rounding of floating points in Ruby

Tags: ruby, floating-point, rounding

I understand due to the inexact representation of floating points, the following code 'feels' inconsistent.

```
"%.1f" % 1.14 # => 1.1
"%.1f" % 1.15 # => 1.1
"%.1f" % 1.16 # => 1.2
"%.0f" % 1.4 # => 1
"%.0f" % 1.5 # => 2
"%.0f" % 1.6 # => 2
```

However, is there an easy way of doing consistent floating points rounding by 5? One way might be to do string manipulation explicitly. Is there an easier way or existent library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want decimal precision, use [BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/classes/BigDecimal.html) instead of floats.

**Edit**: You will have to manually round the number to the desired length before passing it to `%`, otherwise it gets converted to a normal float before being rounded.

```
"%.1f" % BigDecimal('1.15').round(1) => "1.2"
"%.0f" % BigDecimal('1.5').round(0) => "2"
```

Comment: a side question, is x.to_s for a float always yield x (like 1.15.to_s => '1.15')? or would also affected by the inexact representation?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about that one. From my tests, everything seems to come through OK, however Float#to_s does seem to truncate any number with more than 15 digits.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a tiny pertubation, to ensure things that are just under 0.5 in floating-point become just over.

For example,

```
x = 1.15
"%.1f" % (1.000001*x)  # include correction for imprecise floating-point.
```

this will be enough to deal with the formatting problems, while very unlikely to cause a relevant error.

also: an obvious follow-on to my earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949863/inconsistent-rounding-in-ruby), which is fine, but included for completeness.

Comment: Wouldn't it affect some value just slightly blow .5?

Comment: Well, the value `(1/1.000001)*(1.1499999999)` will be incorrectly rounded, but seeing as you're only printing values for display, I think this is fine. If this is a problem, just add some more zeros.

Answer (score 1):

The function `roundthis()` in this example shows how to round numbers in a controllable, consistent way.  Note the small fudge value.  Try running this example without the fudge to see what happens.

```
def roundthis(x, m)
    return (x/m+0.50001).floor*m
end

for x in [1.14, 1.15, 1.16]
    print "#{x}   #{roundthis(x, 0.1)}  \n"
end

for x in [1.4, 1.5, 1.6]
    print "#{x}   #{roundthis(x, 1.0)}  \n"
end
```

This, put into a file named roundtest.rb and executed prints

```
bash> ruby roundtest.rb
1.14   1.1  
1.15   1.2  
1.16   1.2  
1.4   1.0  
1.5   2.0  
1.6   2.0
```

Note the ease of rounding to the nearest 2, 15, 0.005, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by 100, then round, then divide by 100:

```
(1.15 * 100).round / 100.0 # => 1.15
```

It's not exactly elegant, but it avoids using strings.

Comment: this isn't right - there's still a problem, because `1.15` is now represented internally, and imprecisely, using floating-point. Again, as soon as you come to display it, you'll get answers you don't expect.