# Float round bug in ruby?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, rounding

```
ruby-1.8.7 > 1.55.round(1)
 => 1.6 
ruby-1.8.7 > 1.555.round(2)
 => 1.56 
ruby-1.8.7 > 1.155.round(2)
 => 1.16 
ruby-1.8.7 > 10.156.round(2)
 => 10.16
ruby-1.8.7 > 10.155.round(2)
 => 10.15 
ruby-1.8.7 > 10.165.round(2)
 => 10.16
```

What gives? Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

```
ruby-1.9.2 > 10.155.round(2)
 => 10.15 
ruby-1.9.2 > 10.165.round(2)
 => 10.16
```

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950541/consistent-rounding-of-floating-points-in-ruby

Comment: Thanks, this at least provides a workaround for me. And maybe it really is related to floating point imprecision...

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055618/ruby-floating-point-errors

Comment: [Don't](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby/wiki/HowToReject) file it as a bug!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floating point values are not precise.  Your 10.165 is represented on paper/the screen as 10.165, but in memory it's represented as something extremely close to 10.165... whether it rounds up or down is a matter of which direction the error happens to fall in.

If you need accurate handling of fractional numbers, you can either represent them as BigDecimal (with a decimal scale/precision notation), or as Rational (with a fractional numerator/denominator notation).

Answer (score 2):

The Python docs have a good explanation of the fundamental limitations of binary floating-point numbers: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html