# Can anyone tell me why the output is so weird?

Tags: c

I want my output to be

```
0----2----4----6----8----1----1----1----1
```

but I keep getting

```
0----2----------------------------------
```

Basically i want to count from 0 to 16 in increments of 0.4. Here is my code:

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double x;
    for( x = 0.0; x<= 16.0; x = x + 0.4){

        if( fmod(x,2.0) == 0){
            if(x< 10){
                printf("%.0f",x);
            }

            if(x >= 10){
                printf("%.0f",x/10);
            }
        }

        else{
            putchar('-');
        }
    }

    printf("\n");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: floating point precision: fmod(x,2.0) == 0

Comment: Please do not delete your code once you get an answer. This is a public Q&A site, and we want the questions to be useful to others in the future.

Comment: 0.4 cannot be represented in binary floating point, so you can't get exact 2.0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599912/why-do-floats-seem-to-add-incorrectly-in-java read this http://floating-point-gui.de/ [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is due to floating point precision and attempting an exact comparison here:

```
if (fmod(x,2.0) == 0)
```

Either use integers, or use an 'epsilon' test:

```
epsilon = 0.000001;
if (fabs(fmod(x,2.0)) < epsilon)
```

Comment: I used the epsilon but now it is ignoring the 4   output is              ----2---------6----8----1----1----1----

Comment: ty i just used ints by raising everything to a factor of 10

Comment: Suspect you want `fabs()` and not `abs()` which is for `int`.

Comment: Thanks. My C is a little rusty! :)