# Calculation problem in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, double

I'm having slight difficulty in performing a calculation in Java. Here is what I'm trying to do -

`((0.053800 * (500000/1000)) + 4) * 0.85`

In my java application, it returns 26.264999999999997, which if you round up to 2 decimal places, becomes 26.26.

But in MS Excel, the same formula returns 26.265000.. and therefore the rounded result is 26.27.

If my Java application is returning incorrect value, what can I do to correct it?

Comment: @pst see http://ideone.com/Gk8hR

Comment: The main difference is probably between floating-point arithmetic, and real math (as if done by hand).

Comment: Huh?  It'll all be done in double-precision as is since floating-point literals without an "f" modifier are required to be `double` by the Java Language Spec, (and except for `500000/1000` which will be integer division (though it won't lose anything since there's no remainder to that quotient)).

Comment: Why did you round to 2 decimals?  If you round to 3, they round to the same result.  If you round to 1, they round to the same result.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic: According to my Python professor, financial institution's softwares, and financial softwares, have been switching from lossy numerical manipulation.

Comment: Actually the Java app is returning the correct value, according to the IEEE 754 standard. Unfortunately, IEEE 754 arithmetic is different from real number arithmetic, and involves rounding operations on the numbers. Use BigDecimal if you want precise calculation of real numbers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Perl's sprintf not round floating point numbers correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651671/why-does-perls-sprintf-not-round-floating-point-numbers-correctly)

Comment: @sean, I think QuantumMechanic was replying to pst

Comment: @Sean: I'm sure they are, but I was just pointing out that the first commenter's suggestion is incorrect, since the calculation already is being done in double precision.

Comment: @ignis, @QuantumMechanic, my misunderstanding.

Comment: What do you expect from `500 000/1 000`? I would expect it to be 500, and `0.053800 * 500` is't different from `0.0538 * 500` which is `5.38 * 5`. So we're talking about  ((5.38 * 5) + 4) * 0.85, just to simplify it a bit.

Comment: @Atreys, because that's what the requirement is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a much better approximation, which results in the same value in this case:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //double d = ((0.053800 * (500000/1000)) + 4) * 0.85;
        BigDecimal d = ((new BigDecimal(0.053800).multiply(new BigDecimal(500000).divide(new BigDecimal(1000)))).add(new BigDecimal(4))).multiply(new BigDecimal(0.85));
        System.out.println(d.round(MathContext.DECIMAL32));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone who suggested me to use BigDecimal. This does give the desired result.

Answer (score 6):

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651671/why-does-perls-sprintf-not-round-floating-point-numbers-correctly/1651731#1651731) for an explanation of what's going on.