# number formatting

Tags: java, number-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

I'm learning Java so please bear with me for such a simple question. When given a calculation to calculate interest i have this code inputted:

```
 public double calculateTotal(double rate, int n)
 {
     amount = amount * Math.pow((1+rate), (n/12));
     return amount;
 }
```

This returns the answers I'm looking for but keeps adding 0.000000000001 onto the end. 
How would i solve this? A friend advised something called number formatting but i couldn't find a solution.

Comment: If this is for monetary purpose, use `BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) why it isn't a good idea to use a double for currency.

Comment: `n/12` is a integer operation, so for `n = 1` it will be zero, and not `1/12`. Otherwise, `double` can never be 100% precise. You can use `DecimalFormat` to have a nice string representation of your number.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is related to widely known floating point calculation issue.

One of the solutions could be use of `import java.math.BigDecimal`

- [Minimizing the effect of accuracy problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Minimizing_the_effect_of_accuracy_problems) article describes the
  problem.
- Take a look at this ticket [Calculation problem in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222372/calculation-problem-in-java)

**EDIT**

Java does not allow to override operators so the only way to add `BigDecimal`s together is by using `add` method e.g. (assuming your amount is `BigDecimal`. Bear in mind that BigDecimal is immutable so whatever is returned from `calculateTotal` needs to be assigned back to `ammount`

```
// you assign result to amount outside calculateTotal
amount.add(new BigDecimal(Math.pow((1+rate), (n/12))));
```

or

```
// you assign sum to amount inside calculateTotal
amount = amount.add(new BigDecimal(Math.pow((1+rate), (n/12))));
```

Comment: I imported  java.math.BigDecimal. no change. so i changed a couple of the data types to BigDecimal and now the compilers complaining of bad operator types not allowing BigDecimals to be added together. D=

Comment: @cbatothinkofname You should take a look at this question on SO. [Addition for BigDecimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846900/addition-for-bigdecimal)

Comment: Inputted the latest feedback and now it's giving me a totally different answer which is wrong and still giving me long decimals afterwards.

Comment: ah, sorted that problem out... back to the correct answer. only still with long decimal place once again

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned before `BigDecimal` is good option if you need better precision with doubles.

There is nice way to do rounding with `BigDecimal`s. Basically you have to specify scale of the `BigDecimal` instance. Take a look at this sample code:

```
BigDecimal decimalOne = new BigDecimal(0.1950);
BigDecimal decimalTwo = decimalOne.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
BigDecimal decimalThree = decimalOne.setScale(4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN);

System.out.println("decimalOne: " + decimalOne);
System.out.println("decimalTwo: " + decimalTwo);
System.out.println("decimalThree: " + decimalThree);
```

Java 7 would print something like this:

```
decimalOne: 0.195000000000000006661338147750939242541790008544921875
decimalTwo: 0.20
decimalThree: 0.1950
```

Please note that `BigDecimal` instances are immutable and that's why you have to assign result of `setScale` to new instance (`decimalOne` will not be changed).

---

In many financial system `double`s are not used to store currency information; `long` type with specific precision is used instead e.g. for precision 2, value `100` would be `1.00`, `122` would be `1.22` etc. That approach simplifies and seeds up calculations but it is not good for all the systems. However for simplicity of that question I won't dive into that subject too much.